# What is the current hardest encryption in the world(2017)

Tags: encryption, hash

This is probably a repeat of another question. I couldn't find it so I decided to post this one. What is the current hardest to crack encryption algorithm in the world. I don't mean encryption key I mean most advanced algorithm to crack for example what encryption algorithm with a 50-bit encryption key would be the hardest to crack (Im sure the answer is RSA but im still not sure BTW I know its not 2017 yet but it will be soon).

Comment: Depends on your threat model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### OTP

The hardest encryption will forever be One Time Pad, which is impossible to be broken assuming it's correctly executed. This will remain same for all eternity.

> I don't mean encryption key I mean most advanced algorithm to crack for example what encryption algorithm with a 50-bit encryption key would be the hardest to crack

This wouldn't be "most advanced algorithm", this would be "slowest algorithm". Assuming cipher isn't broken (which is true for most ciphers), and we have 50-bit key only, there is one way in making cipher harder to crack - making it slower, which is equally terrible for attacker and user.

Comment: Is it possible to use OTP to encrypt a string in a program like c, c++, php.

Comment: That being said, you should never use OTP in practice.